# Storing data locally on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, sqlite, plist

I'm developing an iOS app, which is my graduation project.. the app is supposed to serve as a social network, where the user could connect to other users. From the data perspective the app needs to store some data locally, and it also have the ability to update these data with a remote server, i.e. the local data are snapshots of a subset of the data that located on the server..

Let's say that the user is able to connect to at most 100 other users, and he/she is also able to see their information, and these info are : textual and small images about each connected user.

I'm wondering what's the most efficient approach to store these data, I've looked at :

- plists
- NSUserDefault
- SQLite3
- Archiving
- Core Data.

But couldn't decide which approach is suitable for my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with CoreData & SQLite ... But we haven't all details of your application, thus, I can be wrong.

Comment: Let's say that the info to be stored are : nickname, id, phone number, and a small picture for each user. And in the worst case a user is connected to 100 users, thus 100 of the info above are stored..

Comment: Don't store the image in db, you'll thank me later. I would avoid using SQIte directly, and use CoreData. Mainly as one day I hope apple will enable XML persistent stores, meaning you can just send that rather than managing the serialization yourself.

Comment: Then go with CoreData & NSSQLiteStoreType as persistent store type.

Comment: Yeah that what I'm going to do, I'd store the images in the file system (e.g. documents) but what about the other textual data ?

Comment: @Jonathan It depends ... If these images are small and he'll have less than 100 images, it's safe and faster for him. Better than learning Transient properties now when he probably doesn't know even CoreData basics.

Comment: I'd like to know what is the most ideal solution, even if there's more that 100 images.

Comment: Then I would go with CoreData, SQLite as persistent store and images stored on file system accessed via core data entity transient property. IOW you can use entity.image property for example, but it will not be stored in DB, but on file system.

Answer (score 0):

You want either SQLite or Core Data. And between those in your particular case, use SQLite. Flexible to work with and you can use the SQL knowledge and SQL data on other platforms. Using SQL both locally and on the server side, should make your development most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data and archiving. I'm not sure if you make a NSManagedObject conform to NSCoding, but if you can use core data on the client side, and then convert to plists (or your own Custom format) for transport over the wire.

Either way, the goal is to a have a parent model class that can serialize all of it's properties.

I know of the Zsync framework for sync'ing data with local and remote core data stores, however I don't believe it works on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple and effective approach is to use sqlite3 and it is very familiar for a developer (as he uses to develop with sql language).