# How should I store a bunch of data locally to display on a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, local-database

I have to display a lot of text preferably pre-formatted or formatted with NSString methods. Each row will have a detailed screen. In the detailed screen another UITableView will have sections for lets say "Definition", "Examples" etc each with only one row. In these rows I will be displaying the text, which spans multiple lines. Should I store all the text in a SQLite database like a column for each section? Are there other ways to store data locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing data locally on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178367/storing-data-locally-on-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few different ways to store application data on your iPhone:

**Using Flat Files**

These are files that contain data in the format you decide it would be best to store it. They are useful for persisting small bits of text data that don't require a complicated structure and a strong relational organization in order to make sense.

**Using Plist files**

Property list files already have a key-value structure in place, that you can use to your advantage if your data lends itself well to this format. Native data types, such as `NSDictionary` and `NSarray` can be serialized and deserialized easily to and from this format.

**Storing key-value data in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html)**

Typically used to store application settings and other small amount of data, NSUserDefaults are useful for holding simple data types without excessive complications.

**Storing Information in an SQL Database**

Useful for when your data is strongly structured and relational and you want to avoid rolling your own file-based data storage structure for time and performance reasons. The SQL language is a powerful tool for retrieving and persisting relational information and you can manage the complexity of your implementation by resorting to wrappers around SQLite, such as [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

**Using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)**

If you plan on persisting and managing a complicated, dynamic object graph, without worrying on how to serialize and deserialize it from storage yourself, Core Data is your best bet. It can help you in many ways, from change tracking and undo support to relational structure maintenance and migration.

---

[Here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1633-how-to-store-iphone-app-data/) is a detailed Oreilly article explaining in more detail the particularities of most of these methods, a great read if you want to develop a solid understanding of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods are...

1. [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)
2. Write to [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html)
3. Write to a file, like for example an [NSDictionary to a plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If all you're storing is a bunch of strings, it might make sense for you to keep it simple and just use NSUserDefaults or make a plist file and [load it into an NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a) when you start your app. If you have actual objects with relationships and sub properties, then I'd look into core data.